# matplotlib tick labels - change date format

Tags: matplotlib

I need to change the date format of the x-axis from what is shown in the picture to MM-YYYY format.

[image: picture]

Comment: wd = data[ (data.R_S_NAME == select_R_S_NAME) \
         & (data.PORT_PADD == select_PORT_PAD) \
         & (data.PORT_CITY == select_PORT_CITY) \
         & (data.FuelType != "OTHER")].copy()

tmp = pd.pivot_table(wd,index=["FuelType","RPT_PERIOD"],\
                    values=['KBBL'],aggfunc=[np.sum])
    
tmp.unstack().transpose().plot(kind='bar',stacked=True, legend=False)
plt.legend(bbox_to_anchor=(1.05, 1), loc=2, borderaxespad=0.)
plt.xlabel('Months')
plt.ylabel('KBBL')

Comment: Look at this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/38194880/2666859