# how to remove redundant date time when x-axis is incontinuous pandas DatetimeIndex

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, series

I want to plot a pandas series which index is incountinuous DatatimeIndex. My code is as follows:

```
import matplotlib.dates as mdates
index = pd.DatetimeIndex(['2000-01-01 00:00:00', '2000-01-01 00:01:00',
           '2000-01-01 00:02:00', '2000-01-01 00:03:00',
           '2000-01-01 00:07:00',
           '2000-01-01 00:08:00'],
          dtype='datetime64[ns]')
df = pd.Series(range(6), index=index)
print(df)
plt.plot(df.index, df.values)
plt.gca().xaxis.set_major_formatter(mdates.DateFormatter("%M"))
plt.show()
```

The output is:[image]
But the result is not what I really want, because 2000-01-01 00:04:00 is also plotted on the image. The desired outcome is that on the x-axis 03:00 is next to 07:00 and the image should be a straight line. Hope for your great idea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One possible solution is convert index to `string` by [`strftime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DatetimeIndex.strftime.html) and use [`Series.plot`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.plot.html):

```
s = pd.Series(range(6), index=index)
print(s)
2000-01-01 00:00:00    0
2000-01-01 00:01:00    1
2000-01-01 00:02:00    2
2000-01-01 00:03:00    3
2000-01-01 00:07:00    4
2000-01-01 00:08:00    5
dtype: int32

s.index = s.index.strftime('%M')
s.plot()
```

Another solution is plot by `arange` and then add [`xticks`](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html?highlight=xticks#matplotlib.pyplot.xticks):

```
x = np.arange(len(s.index))
plt.plot(x, s)
plt.xticks(x, s.index.strftime('%M'))
plt.show()
```

---

[image: graph]

Comment: In my project, I use `LineCollection` to draw a multi-color line. You can take a look at my former question. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44642966/how-to-plot-multi-color-line-if-x-axis-is-date-time-index-of-pandas   `LineCollection` requires coordinates are able to be 'float'. Although this method is very good, but it  can't be used in my project. Thank you anyway.

Comment: @JZeng I think this answer is directly applicable to your problem. Have you tried to use it? What is the problem?

Comment: Sorry for my carelessness, this method really works for my project. But the xticks is too dense. I want to show 'year' not 'minute', but I found set locator and formatter do not help. do you have any good idea? Thanks a lot for your kindness.

Comment: `plt.xticks(x, s.index.strftime('%Y'))` does not work? maybe need change it by http://strftime.org/.

Comment: for example, there are too many minutes of 2012, if I use `plt.xticks(x, s.index.strftime(%Y))`, there are too many 2012 at x-axis, each minute a 2012, but I want only one 2012 for a year's data.

Comment: Do you think something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38186557/2901002) ?

Comment: Their answer may not help me. I want labels auto generated from index, because I do not know whether there are same data in 2011 as 2012 or not.

Comment: It seems it is more complicated, is possible create new question? It seems need some matplotlib guru knowledge (not me)... Sorry. :(